# COUNT value mismatch in Eloquent JOIN query of Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Here is my query

```
$allInspiration = $allInspiration->select('businesses.id as business_id','businesses.owner_name',
                                'businesses.user_id as business_user_id','businesses.business_name',
                                DB::raw("COALESCE(CONCAT(customers.cust_fname, ' ', customers.cust_lname), 'N/A') as customer_name"),
                                'business_reviews.id as review_master_id','business_reviews.rating',
                                'business_reviews.comment','business_reviews.review_image',
                                DB::raw("COUNT(inspiration_likes.id) as like_count"),
                                DB::raw("COUNT(inspiration_comments.id) as comment_count"),
                                'business_reviews.customer_id','business_reviews.created_at',
                                'business_reviews.status')
                            ->join('businesses','business_reviews.business_id', '=', 'businesses.id')
                            ->leftJoin('customers','business_reviews.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
                            ->rightJoin('inspiration_likes','business_reviews.id', '=', 'inspiration_likes.review_id')
                            ->rightJoin('inspiration_comments','business_reviews.id', '=', 'inspiration_comments.review_id')
                            ->where('business_reviews.inspiration',1);
```

The problem is, there are two rows in "inspiration_likes" and two rows in "inspiration_comments". But my like_count and comment_count is both returning 4.

How can I solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` function

```
COUNT(DISTINCT inspiration_likes.id)

COUNT(DISTINCT inspiration_comments.id)
```